# student doesn't bring a homework in a 1-to-1 class

Tags: teaching, remote-teaching

What should a tutor do? I have students who even ask for homeworks, because they have desire for new knowledge in math. However, in my experience, most pupils hate mathematics. Should I ask their parent to be checking on that? I do private online classes for students 5th-13th Grade.

Comment: You talk about students who ask for homework and others who hate math.  Are either of them bringing their homework?  Did you tell them when the homework is due and to bring it? What happens when you ask for it? Please give more details.

Comment: Typically the ones who hate math don't bring their homework to the next lesson.

Answer (score 2):

I tutor students on zoom.  I tell them to email me their homework by 5 PM the day before the next lesson. If they do, I have a chance to see how they did with the work BEFORE we meet.  If they don't, I get in touch with them and tell them that there is no point in meeting if they haven't done the work. Sometimes they will ask if they can send the work a little later the same day and I allow it and other times we cancel the lesson.  This works with college students.

Since you tutor younger students I suggest that you soften this approach a little as well as involving the parents. Tell the parents the student hasn't been bringing the work.  Tell the parents you will be implementing a policy where they must email the homework in advance. If they do, it will be win -win as they will be keeping up with your work as well as giving you a chance to assess them before you meet.  If they don't explain to the parents that you will be cancelling the lessons until the homework is done.  Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the student and the parents straight. They are paying to improve the student's maths skills. They are paying for extra lessons because the student isn't at the standard they would like. For this improvement to occur as much, if not more, must happen outside the lesson in the student's own time. That's what I tell them. I also say if they want to change tutor be wary of those who just turn up and take money. But then I am fortunate I have enough work to turn down students who don't study.

Comment: In my opinion a person who hates math can still be in need of math lessons.